# Best way to store store_id in dedicated database table

Tags: magento-enterprise

I've created a module that stores a CMS-block like entity in a dedicated database. Just like a widget. Lets call it `my_custom_widget`.

I want to determine wheter `my_custom_widget` should be used for store (id: 1) and/or store 2 (id: 2).

In my `Form.php` file I have this node:

```
$fieldset->addField('store_id', 'multiselect', array(
    'name'      => 'store_id',
    'label'     => Mage::helper('my_custom_widget_extended')->__('Store View'),
    'title'     => Mage::helper('my_custom_widget_extended')->__('Store View'),
    'required'  => true,
    'values'    => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true),
));
```

This is somehow copied from a core module of Magento, but slightly modified for my needs.

However, if I want to save it, it returns an error because the PDO-adapter cannot store an array in a database obviously.

Would I rather:
1. insert it twice, foreach store (without creating two visible entities in the grid)
2. just store a comma seperated string?

Whats the prefered, best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_beforeSave` method in your model class and set store_id as `serialized`.

For eg: if your table coulmn name is store_id then use it like:

```
protected function _beforeSave(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object){
  $this->setStoreId(serialize($this->getStoreId()));
  return parent::_beforeSave($object);
}
```

And use this method to get Array values of store id while you call getStoreId():

```
protected function _beforeLoad(){
    $this->setStoreId(unserialize($this->getStoreId()));
    return parent::_beforeLoad();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not plan to search\filter collection by a store id I'll recommend you to store the "store_id" as a comma separated value in the field of the main table. If you planning to make a search by a store id - use separate table (two columns: the `entity_id` which a foreign key to main table id and the `store_id`) with an index on the store id field for a better performance.